# perpendicular distance between midpoint and a line

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

There is a well known formula for projection of a point **b** onto a line **a**. The sought point **p** can be expressed as **p** = x **a**, where x is **a** dot **b** divided by **a** dot **a**. 
[image: projection]

I have a somewhat similar situation. 
[image]

I have a midpoint **m** of a line segment starting at **b** and ending at **c**. I draw a line through **m**, that is perpendicular to the line segment. This line intersects the line **a** at some point **p**. Since **p** is on the line **a** it can be expressed as **p** = x **a** . So I want to find x expressed in the terms of **a**, **b** and **c**. The formula has to be similar (expressed in vectors) to what I have for projection. I am trying to avoid using the cartesian coordinates of type (x1,y1), because there are 3 points involved and using coordinates would give a very complicated formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Step 1: Project $\frac12(\mathbf b + \mathbf c)$ onto $\mathbf c - \mathbf b,$
producing a vector $\mathbf q$.

Step 2: Project $\mathbf a$ onto $\mathbf c - \mathbf b,$
producing a vector $\mathbf r$.

Then $x = \dfrac{\lVert \mathbf q\rVert}{\lVert \mathbf r\rVert}.$

Comment: What a beautiful solution!